# How to 'inject' the "read more" link into a textfield / paragraph (inline)

Tags: views, nodes

Due to client's demand the situation is that I can't use the default (trimmed) body text as a teaser text in a view listing nodes. Instead I have an extra text field which contains 2-3-4 paragraphs so that the client has 100% control of what the teaser text would look like etc.

I would need to place a "read more" link at the end of that custom teaser text. I tried different methods to place such a link inline with the teaser text – but couldn't find a way to actually have a working setup.

- I tried the read more module – which works fine with standard situation, replacing/placing the "read more" link inline – but that won't help me here.
- I tried overriding the field in views – but that won't let me place the "read more" *inside* the last paragraph. Either I keep properly formated paragraphs, or I use "inline" or "inline-block" for the p but then the paragraph-structure collapses.
- I also tried the read more control module – but that seems to solve problems that I don't have (hiding "read more" links if there is not 'more' to read)

I suppose this must be possible – and would gladly appreciate any tipps or pointers that would lead me in some direction.. thnx!

Comment: Have you seen the 'Long text with Summary' field type?  It allows the user to specifically set the teaser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is simply to get the read more link to appear visually inline with your last paragraph, I think you can do that with pure CSS.  As you noted, formatting all your `<p>` tags as inline elements will break the paragraph structure.  You can avoid this simply by using a `:last-child` selector, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/hdys6w2j/

That said, if you are set on having the readmore link injected into your last p tag, I guess you could throw some code like this in your custom module:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$vars) {

  //Programmatically generate the readmore link
  $read_more_link = l('Read more', 'node' . $vars['node']->nid);

  if (!empty($vars['content']['my_field'][0]['#markup'])) {

    //Replace the last </p> tag with <a href="/path/to/my/node">Read More</a></p>
    $vars['content']['my_field'][0]['#markup'] = preg_replace(
       '/\<\/p\>$/', 
       $read_more_link . '</p>',
       $vars['content']['my_field'][0]['#markup']
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I just didn't come up with the selector. In my case it actually had to be the :last-of-type selector since the more-span is inside the same parent. But now it works. Great.